# How to get to play easier games?

Tags: league-of-legends

I started out with League Of Legends a few days ago. At the moment I'm level 11, and things are getting hard for me. In fact, in PVP games I always have the feeling my opponents are way more experienced (meaning way better) than I am, and I routinely get destroyed on the lanes without being able to do much against it.

I'd like to **reduce the difficulty of PVP games** to compete with players that are an even matchup for me. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is. By losing.

League of Legends has a matchmaking system that attempts to pair players with similar hidden ratings. This rating exist for all queues (Ranked games don't use the same rating that Normal games do).

Due to that, to face worse players you need to make your rating lower, and the only way to do that is to lose, as the hidden rating goes up/down based on wins/losses.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that most games that have PvP content use a similar system to match players. However, if there are not enough people in the same rank that are currently looking to be matched, the system usually expands its search towards higher and lower ranks until enough players have been found for a full game. This means that at times when there is a low population in a game, you can still be matched outside of your skill range.

Answer (score 1):

While what Oak said in the other answer is true, I don't think that it applies to you since you mentioned being level 11. I've played games on my low level smurf; and I've noticed that its rare for many players to be around the same level as I am.

This is likely due to the fact that there just isn't enough of a sub level 30 player base to evenly match people, so you may get matched with players many levels higher or even level 30.

And while skill and experience factors into it. I'd say the biggest reason you'd be having trouble is that players with higher levels have more masteries (the keystone especially represents a large spike in power) and even runes. These two can make a massive impact on a player's performance.

So to answer your actual question; I'd say there's nothing you can do to make the games easier.
That being said, you should just aim to do the best you can and learn from it. As you keep playing, not only will you get better, you'll get more runes and masteries, and also start playing with a larger player base (meaning more people of the same skill level).

Comment: It's because a lot of low level players are't actually new but just leveling up another annount due to bans/smurfs.

Answer (score 1):

While what the other answers have said is true, you should also take the following into consideration:

Remember not to let your friends play on your account, ever. Riot keeps their smurf detection methods secret so it may also consider other factors to determine your hidden MMR. (In DotA2, they do this by checking your GPM, XPM, KDA, Damage output and CS)

Avoid queuing with friends who're much better than you. It's been confirmed that queuing with players who have higher MMR would make the game much harder for yourself.